# jQuery $.position() on Safari & Chrome

Tags: jquery, svg, raphael

I have an issue using $.position to retrieve the relative x/y offset on an element.
It was mentioned before that both Safari and Chrome differ in handling it as the others.

I'm using Raphael-JS.

To cut the long story short, what I have is an SVG element wrapped by the parent, **centered** DIV wrapper:

```
<div> 
    <svg>
        <path/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

In every browser an object returned by $.position which runs on 'path' element gives more or less the correct value. Both Chrome and Safari return negative values for x offset and 0 for y.

Any help will be appreciated,
Best regards

Comment: Can you post some of the CSS that controls the display of those elements? When I try a very simple test, Safari and Chrome give me the exact same results that Firefox does.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2Pavc/1/ try it both in Firefox and Safari. The latter returns zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Raphael’s `cx` and `cy` attributes, like in `circle.attr("cx")` and `circle.attr("cy")`.

Comment: then try `x` and `y`.  dump `raphaelElement.attr()` and see what attributes it has?

Comment: Every object contains only four properties: fill, path, stroke, stroke-width.

Comment: Solved by using getBBox().x and getBBox().y respectively.